# Are there statistics that show if clothing choices have an effect on sexual assault rates?

Tags: crime

I am curious to know if women who dress provocatively are more or less likely to be victims of sexual assault. The best way to find out would be to conduct a study in a country where a considerable number of women wear more modest attire and a considerable number of women do not, and then compare the sexual assault statistics between the two groups. Conducting the study in the same country should reduce the influence of other variables, such as cultural differences or differences in reporting. A potential country to use for this study could be Malaysia, where many women wear the hijab and many do not. The study should also consider other factors, like the age of the perpetrator and victim, time, and motives.

I was unable to find any statistics about this topic. Although there are a lot of results for how people view revealing clothing and sexual assault, none of the results show a direct connection between the two. The one study I did find which had relevant results was called [She Dresses to Attract, He Perceives Seduction: A Gender Gap in Attribution of Intent to Women’s Revealing Style of Dress and its Relation to Blaming the Victims of Sexual Violence](https://vc.bridgew.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1202&context=jiws) and it surveyed respondents about whether they liked wearing revealing clothes and if they experienced four types of sexual victimization, then looked for correlations. This seems to be a complicated way of obtaining data, when a more direct way would be to look at the clothing worn by victims of sexual assault. The study also didn't focus on the causality between the two, as is clear from its title.

Comment: Even if you could show that what someone wears influences this what does that mean in the end? Are you suggesting that clothing get regulated in order to prevent people from harming others?

Comment: @JoeW I have nothing to say to people who think I am suggesting something whenever I ask a question.

Comment: I am surprised the close vote is for "not related to politics". Not hard to find articles like this one https://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/jun/24/malaysia.religion?CMP=gu_com which clearly mark this as a political issue.

Comment: This is a commonly used tactic to shift the blame to the victim by suggesting that the crime happened because of the clothes that they wore instead of the actions taken by the person who did the crime.

Comment: Just read the question a little closer and noticed study you linked is linking clothing to trying to seduce others which is a sign of the problem of tying to link clothing to actions of others.

Comment: Indirectly, one could try suss out if countries with strict modesty laws do much better (while taking into consideration factors which affect victims' willingness to report rapes)  They don't really *seem* to do much better.  In any case, this subject tends to be very contentious (c.f. *slut shaming*), not without reason:  rapes are committed by men and the driving factor seems to be male societal views of coercive sex - what % minority of men think it's OK, not female "invitation" to get assaulted.  So while there may very well be a nugget of good research to be had:  high career suicide risk

Comment: Voting to reopen because I don't see why this is not a political question (per above). I am also not interested in anything that is related to the words 'blame' or 'perceive'. Insofar as they are relevant to this question, it's that there is a lot of literature related to those words and not to the question that is actually asked.

Comment: Not a scientific study but https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/rape-victims-clothes-displayed-brussels-belgium-debunk-victim-blaming-myth-a8152481.html

Comment: I think this is a hard study to make a comparison between two nations, as there are worlds of differences between what counts as a sexual assault between some nations, not to mention acceptance of women making such accusations.

Comment: @hszmv yeah, which is why OP is looking for a study within a single nation, though I don't think it belongs on Politics.SE. Maybe Skeptics.SE?

Comment: @Allure Although nuclear power is a political issue, the physics behind it would be off-topic here. You make clear in the comments that you are not interested in the implications of the data or specific policy proposals. I also think this question would be a better fit for skeptics.SE, in fact it has [already been asked there](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/is-a-woman-who-dresses-sexually-suggestively-more-likely-to-get-raped).

Comment: One obvious problem is: if you believe sexily dressed women are asking for it, at least in cases of date/acquaintance rape, then presumably you don't think they get raped at all, because they're always willing? This study would require a legal system which is able to identify rape in most cases, which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @StuartF if you are insinuating that I "believe in it", note that that was not in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Sexual assault surely has a demographic profile, and that profile has clothing preference.

However, if you were to make affected demographic group wear different clothing, the correlation will likely go away. The same demographics will suffer the same amount of sexual assault, now clothed differently.

This is because correlation is not casuation.

When a cheetah attacks its prey, it is more likely to kill the slowest moving goat. But it is futile to recommend athletics training to a goat herd, because the cheetah will just as reliably catch the slowest of now-faster goats. The amount of goats eaten will not change. Individual running lessons may change outcome for a specific goat, but that does not suggest any policy changes.

Comment: Is there any data to support the claim that "The same demographics will suffer the same amount of sexual assault, now clothed differently"?

Comment: There is data that most sexual assault actually happens when the perpertator and the victim already know each other, even if passingly, and at this point clothing is already irelevant.

Comment: There is anecdotal evidence that some rapists choose victims who look quiet, meek, and unable to defend themselves. If nothing else, a stiletto heel is a better weapon than a ballet pump. So clothing choices may play a very indirect role, but it's unlikely to be the role that misogynistic politicians and police chiefs claim.